# Looking to get a timeout/wait command in linux equivalent to ms-dos

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file

I'm trying to make a timeout in my .sh file that is the same as the one in my .bat file, but I'm not sure of how to do it... at all.
It's just a simple "wait" command that last 3 seconds and has no purpose other than waiting
Here is my msdos code:

```
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
```

Can this be done in .sh?

Comment: Just use `sleep 3` instead of timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
sleep 3
```

so, just use sleep and the given time in seconds.